# Stub a property which is in the concrete class but not on the interface for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, mef, rhino-mocks

I have a class which has more information then my inteface. It has a property which I did not expose in my interface.

```
 public interface IViewResolver
{
    object GetViewFor(string viewName);

}
```

I want now to implement a MefViewResolver based on that interface.

```
public class ViewResolver : IViewResolver
{


    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IView,IViewMetaData>> Views { get; set; }



    public object GetViewFor(string viewName)
    {
        var view = Views.Where(x => x.Metadata.Name == viewName).FirstOrDefault();

        return view == null ? null : view.Value;
    }

}
```

My SUT gets a IResolver per constructor injection loaded with my mefViewResolver. In my unit test I would like to pre-set my Views property from the outside without using mef or being mef specific in my interface. 
Basically I want to set the Views with an expected value and see if my viewmodel which uses the IViewResolver returns the preset view...
How can I stub the views property even if it does not exists on my interface...

If I am on the wrong path... any corrections would much appriciated..

Thanks D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test your ViewModel (and not the Resolver), which is only aware of the IViewResolver interface, you shouldn't have any problem: the only method (according to the code provided) that the ViewModel can access is `GetViewFor`. All you need to do is return the appropriate View for each test case, given the View name. In RhinoMocks it should be something like:

```
// Arrange the test objects
var viewResolverMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IViewResolver>();
viewResolverMock.Stub(x => x. GetViewFor(thisTestViewName).Return(thisTestView);
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(viewResolverMock);

// Do the actual operation on your tested object (the view model)
var actualResult = myViewModel.DoSomethingWithTheView();

// Assert 
AssertAreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

Comment: You might want to `Stub` the call to viewResolverMock.GetViewFor(...) instead of creating an expectation, since it is only a query and you have an assertion for the result from the MyViewModel.DoSometingWithTheView() which is assumed to depend on the IViewResolver.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I am trying to test 2 thinks at one time. I should test my mefviewresolver independently and should rely on it that it works in my view model test. With that I can stub my GetViewFor without worries... Thanks again =)